# Did a Terminator skeleton head ever talk?

Tags: terminator-series

In any movie of the *Terminator* series, including the TV show *Terminator: The Sarah Conner Chronicles*, was there ever a scene that had a Terminator skeleton head talking? Not Terminator liquid models like the T-1000.

I mean without human skin or covering the face with cloth or any other thing.

Comment: Well, we know they can because it's [implied here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8r354VUktU8) in *Salvation* (where a terminator skeleton mimics Kyle), but we don't actually see it.

Comment: [Can Terminators without human tissue talk?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133041/can-terminators-without-human-tissue-talk/133065?s=9|0.0000#133065) - In the TV show, yes.

Comment: @Walt people why you giving answer in comment section? give the answer in proper way. for the answer its not enough to said YES. you have to give proof witch episode or witch scene

Comment: As I said, you don't actually *see* it in my example, so that's not a real answer to your question. I merely commented that it's *possible*. [BTW, I have no idea why, but SE only informed me of your comment *now* even though it seems to be 8 days old.]

Comment: There are no witches in the Terminator movies. Also, irrc that salvation scene, when the skin job terminator first meets a teenage kyle reese in a junk yard is the only example of a toaster head terminator talking. So @walt comment is the answer, unless there is something in SCC that does it.

Answer (score 1):

### Unskinned Terminators can talk.

In [Terminator: Salvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Salvation) we see a T-800 Endoskeleton speaking during the fight sequence between Kyle, John and an endo in the Terminator Factory. It imitates Reese to lure John to it.

[image]

> **VO:** *Connor. Connor help. Help! Connor it's Kyle! Help!*
>
> [John Rounds the corner only to come face to face with the
> endoskeleton Terminator. He's been tricked]

Note that at least the last couple of words are said ***with the Terminator in full view.***

---

Similarly, we see an unskinned T-888 speaking in [Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles - The Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles)

[image]

> **Dr. Fleming:** *I have a camera. Would it be alright if I...*
>
> **Terminator:** *Move away*
>
> [The Terminator then proceeds to remove its clothing revealing that it has no skin]